# cannot achieve 120Hz refresh rate with Nvidia graphics card

Tags: drivers, nvidia, graphics

My monitor supports 120Hz refresh rate and I set it in the settings as well. But I can clearly see the difference when I switch back and forth between Intel integrated graphics and my NVIDIA 1660ti. The NVIDIA doesn't show smooth transition as I can see in the Intel graphics. So I tested with in testufo.com to check. My doubts were true, Nvidia shows around 110 and in Intel exactly 120 Hz. How to fix this problem?
Thanks in advance.

I am using Ubuntu 18.04 and NVIDIA driver ver. 440 (proprietary, tested)

Comment: Please add Ubuntu version and NVidea driver version via [edit](https://askubuntu.com/posts/1250662/edit) to your question.

Comment: I added the versions in the original post